# upgrade to ubuntu natty 11.04, or wait?

Tags: ubuntu-natty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if I can just upgrade? How will this effect my ROS install if at all?

Should I wait a few more months?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10468/upgrade-to-ubuntu-natty-11.04,-or-wait?/) by [xalu](https://answers.ros.org/users/754/xalu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2011-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At this point all the core libraries are available in Ubuntu Natty 11.04.  Diamondback status for debian packages can be seen [here](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/diamondback.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are still using CTurtle, you should upgrade to Diamondback. CTurtle is not available for 11.04, but Diamondback is by now.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-07-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1